# Why does my sour-dough bread have a tail?

Tags: sourdough

I just baked this bread using sour dough. Everything looks fine until I take it out of the owen. Pre-oven it looks like the first picture, but when I take it out it got a "tail" (see red circle in second picuture). The texture seems to be fine. What am I doing wrong?

Before owen:
[image]

After owen:
[image]

Sliced:
[image]

Comment: You could have scored it